# Retrieve data from the inverse of a one to many relationship

Tags: arrays, laravel

I am trying to access data of the inverse `one to many` relationship.

My Dealer Model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);

}
```

My User Model:

```
public function dealer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Dealer::class,);

}
```

I try and retrieve the data using from the dealer using:

```
$variable = \Auth::user()->dealer()->get();
```

I have the following array when I perform `dd($variable)`.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1291 ▼
 #items: array:1 [▼
  0 => App\Dealer {#1293 ▼
  #guard: "dealer"
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "dealers"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:34 [▶]
  #original: array:34 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
     }
   ]
  }
```

The info I am trying to access is under #attributes.

If i use `$dealer = \Auth::user()->dealer()->get()->toArray();` I get the array as follows.

```
array:1 [▼
0 => array:32 [▼
"id" => 1
"admin_id" => 1
"name" => "Example"
"contact" => "Cheree"
"email" => "cheree@example.co.za"
"access" => "Standard"
```

How do I access the data in the #attributes?

Comment: you can't directly access it like that because this is array of multiple records and you will have to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `array` in another `array`. So you have an array of arrays. To access the inner arrays elements you will first have to chose from the outer one.

So you will have to call: `$varaible[0]['name']`

This means you will get the first (e.g. 0) element of `$variable` which is an array and then the element where the key is "name" from this array.

@edit

You can simply remove `->get()` and it should work by calling `Auth::user()->dealer`or `Auth::user()->dealer()->first()`

Comment: Sorry now I feel like an idiot. I initially retrieved information from a `many to one` relationship. I used `Auth::user()->dealer()get()->toArray();` This gave me the `array` above. Is there an easier way to get the `dealer` info without using `toArray`

Comment: Does a User have One dealer and One Dealer Many Users? If so, you might have an error in your dealer() relationship. Can you add the models to your code? @customcms

Comment: Thanks a ton... Please send me your invoice